# I do not want to see empty buffer after makeprg in VIM

Tags: django, vim

Using VIM I want to execute current sql file and see results. I've tried the following (`./manage.py dbshell` is a Django wrapper over `psql`)

```
nmap <silent> <Leader>r :make<CR>
autocmd FileType sql set makeprg=cat\ %\\\|./manage.py\ dbshell
```

It works fine. But after *Press ENTER or type command to continue* VIM always shows me empty buffer (maybe it is error list). How to skip its opening?

If I run the same in command mode it will be as I've expected (without annoying buffers)

```
:!cat %|./manage.py dbshell
```

My SQL script contains a single select statement. And the magic buffer looks like:
[image]

Comment: A screenshot would be useful to identify that mistery buffer. if it's the quickfix window, you could add something like `| cclose` at the end of your mapping.

Comment: Hmm… I was expecting a normal statusline but you use powerline which I can't read. Anyway, this thing is *not* the quickfix or error list. Could you post  the content of manage.py?

Comment: @romainl It is very, *very* unlikely manage.py is the cause of this, there are not much options for an external program to control vim (like +clientserver), and it would be very strange if those options are used only when std* is a tty (with `!cat % | ./manage.py dbshell` everything is stated to be fine).

Comment: You are probably right. But it doesn't hurt to have *all* the informations.

Comment: @romainl It does. If there were full manage.py code I would’ve read it all before thinking about other options: like the fact that buffer name looks like part of SQL code and script in question is a database shell. It means that this question would waste my and other experts’ (BTW what is the term for the person who gives answers here?) time for reading irrelevant data and OP time for posting it. If you really had ***all*** the information you would be reading it *infinite* time.

Comment: Well I guess you are right. And I have no idea how to call "us".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is likely to be wrong `'errorformat'` option. Try doing

```
:make!
```

(with bang!) and see whether this window appears. If it does not, this is true and you should read `:h 'errorformat'` and also set it in addition to `'make'`. Or just never use plain `:make` without bang and forget about jumping to errors (if that script is able to output information about errors).

---

Another idea: Could you show the output of

```
:au ShellCmdPost,QuickFixCmdPre,QuickFixCmdPost
```

? It may also be a problem of some plugin or vimrc code that is launched on one of these three events.

---

By the way, you have two things in commands you posted that may be improved. First, mapping should be written as `nnoremap`. You don’t need remapping here and it may save your time when you add some other mapping to your vimrc.

Second, use `setlocal` in autocmd, not `set`. With `set` you set default `'makeprg'` for all buffers that will be opened after sql one.